# Getting the Tag name of a element crawled with DomCrawler in PHP

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit, web-crawler

I am crawling my html view with PHPUnit, using [DomCrawler](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler)

```
$element = $crawler->filter("#myElement");
```

Once I have the element, how could I know the kind of tag that it is? (`<input>`, `<select>`, ...)

I know I could do this:

```
$element = $crawler->filter("input#myElement");
```

but I need to extract the name of the tag, and store it in a variable

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it, this should work:

```
$element = $crawler->filter("#myElement");
$name = $element->getNode(0)->tagName;
```

The `Crawler::getNode(index)` returns a DOMElement that has the `tagName` read only field.

Comment: The latest stable release seems to have the method getNode() as protected

Comment: I've checked and from 2.4 and up it is public

Comment: I have added `"symfony/dom-crawler": "*"` to my composer json, and the version that downloads still has it protected. I think 2.4 is not yet in the channel. What configuration do you recommend me?

Comment: What's in the composer.lock file? Which version does it download?

Comment: How to get tag name in Symfony 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

Update: nowadays it is

```
$element = $crawler->filter("#myElement");
$name = $element->nodeName();
```

... which is actually a wrapper for

```
$crawler->getNode(0)->nodeName
```